# Reverse proxy nginx serves same website differently

Tags: nginx-reverse-proxy

I have set up `nginx` to reverse proxy, but I am having a weird problem. If I browse to

```
http://www.example.com/
```

The website displays correctly. However, if I browse to

```
example.com
```

I am sent to a different site!

This is part of my nginx config file:

```
server {
listen 80;

server_name www.example.com;

location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8051;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I got this to work, I think the problem is that browser cache.